# Ordering of Native and ReactJS events

Tags: events, reactjs, dom-events

So I have this example to show the issue I am running into with some code I am working on right now (can't post the exact code for numerous reasons).

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jPxzar

```
var Test1 = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {
      events: ['Demo loaded'],
      buttonClicked: false
    };
  },

  componentWillMount: function() {
    document.addEventListener('click', this.onDocumentClick);
  },

  onDocumentClick: function() {
    var message = 'on document click event (button clicked: ' + this.state.buttonClicked + ')';
    this.setState({
      events: this.state.events.concat([message]),
      buttonClicked: false
    });
  },

  onButtonClick: function() {
    this.setState({
      events: this.state.events.concat(['on button click event']),
      buttonClicked: true
    });
  },

  render: function() {
    return (
      <span>
        <button onClick={this.onButtonClick}>Button</button>
        <div>Events:</div>
        <ul>
          {this.state.events.map(function(message) {
            return <li>{message}</li>;
          })}
        </ul>
      </span>
    );
  }
});

React.render(
  <Test1 />, 
  document.getElementById('mount-point'));
```

Here I have a component that in the mounting of adds a native click event handler on the document as I need to track any click that happens anywhere on the page, not just within this component.  I also have a button that has a ReactJS event handler.  If I click anywhere outside of the button, everything works fine.  If I click the button, both events are fired however the native event is fired first and then the React event however I need the React event to be triggered first.

How can I make sure that natively attached events are always executed after React events?

Answer (score 2):

Based on my debugging experience, there are two click event handlers are already registered on "root" element before the actual component tree is rendered. So, any dom event listeners on "root" element are added from index 2. So, always the react events are fired first and then dom events on "root" element.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the events are being fired in the order that the listeners were added.  I did some digging and found some information in the [DOM3 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#event-flow) that seems to support this, but I'm still not quite sure what the intended behavior is supposed to be.

In any case, I tested my theory and it appears to give the desired effect: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EjLRbK

To summarize: you're currently creating the native event listener in `componentWillMount`. This function executes before the component's initial call to `render`, so the native event listener is created first.  If you change this to `componentDidMount`, it will execute after the initial call to `render`, and the event listener in `render` will be created first, and will be called first when clicking the button in your example code.